# Javascript drag and drop - do you have to use dragover?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to figure out how to properly do drag and drop, and from what I read on MDN, it sounds like i should be able to indicate via dragenter that a drop is possible on that element. I simply haven't been able to get it to work, but when I switch to drag over, it seems to start working. I don't really want to register a dragover event handler tho, because I don't need that to be called every time the mouse moves inside an area. Is there a way to completely avoid registering a dragover handler for drag and drop?

This is what I have working with dragover:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="a" draggable="true">a</div>
    <div id="c">b</div>
</div>

<style>
    div {
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    #c {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
    }


</style>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    var a = document.getElementById('a')
    var c = document.getElementById('c')

    a.addEventListener('dragstart', function(event) {
        var dt = event.dataTransfer;

        dt.setData("object/jsObject", {test:1});
        dt.setData("text/plain", "test one");
    })
    c.addEventListener('dragover', function(event) {
        if(event.preventDefault){
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        console.log(event)
    })
    c.addEventListener('drop', function(event) {
        console.log(event)
        c.innerHTML = 'dropped '+event.dataTransfer.getData(event.dataTransfer.types[0])
        event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
    })

</script>
```

Is there any way to replace dragover with dragenter?

UPDATE:

Oh here's something interesting, apparently the HTML5 drag and drop api [is absolute shite](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2009/09/the_html5_drag.html). I was beginning to come to that conclusion myself.

Comment: Can include `html` , `js` at Question ?

Comment: use jquery ui for drag and drop

Comment: @guest271314 Sure I'll add the stuff I'm testing